# Try This API for swagger is not working in wso2 EI 6.4

Tags: wso2, swagger, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

I generated the API using swagger yaml file. API is generated succesfully and i am able to see json as well while checking by clicking on "Swagger" link. But when i am trying to test this API by clicking on "Try This API", this link does not seem to be working.

http://localhost:8280/CustomAPI:v1.0.0?swaggertryit

Is there any configuration, i am missing? Any pointer/help is really appreciated.

Thanks,
Vipin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Swagger tryit and swagger json functionality is not enable by default in wso2 EI 6.4. Its being enhanced in wso2 EI 6.6. To get done this functionality in 6.4, please add below property in conf/carbon.xml file inside tag HttpGetRequestProcessors and restart wso2.

```
<Processor>
 <Item>swagger.json</Item>           
 <Class>org.wso2.carbon.mediation.transport.handlers.requestprocessors.swagger.format.SwaggerJsonProcessor</Class>
</Processor>
<Processor>
 <Item>swagger.yaml</Item>           
<Class>org.wso2.carbon.mediation.transport.handlers.requestprocessors.swagger.format.SwaggerYamlProcessor</Class>
</Processor>
<Processor>
  <Item>swaggertryit</Item>
  <Class>org.wso2.carbon.tryit.SwaggerTryitRequestProcessor</Class>
</Processor>
```

Answer (score 0):

Swagger feature was introduced in EI 6.6.0 according to the release notes. https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI660/About+this+Release

Comment: Hi Arunan,  I am able to generate APIs using swagger definition. Its only the testing part where i am not able to proceed. I am not sure whether that is not applicable to WSO2 6.4 version.